# How to render a 3d object model(fbx,obj,collada etc) in firefox browser

Tags: 3d, webgl, collada, fbx

I am developing an onLine application where users can upload 3d models, reposition them on the screen and resize them also. Is it possible to render 3d models in the browser generated from various 3d design softwares. If yes then please anybody help me how to do that ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Collada XML structure is somewhat manageable; I did a half-assed collada-to-json converter http://hexaflexagon.com/src/web/omino.com2/experiments/webgl/OmCollada.py, and from there it's not far to render as triangles and stuff (after you learn WebGL).

But ThreeJs library has collada reader built in, and is a shorter path most likely. 

Not sure about other format...

Comment: Thanks David, I will check your code and threejs has inbuilt features for rendering 3d objects but it does not show some objects correctly.